# Find all nonzero matrices $A\in M_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ which are not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all nonzero (with every element $\neq$0) matrices $A\in M_2(\Bbb Z_3)$ which are not invertible, and explain why they aren't invertible.

It seems simple indeed, but I'm not sure how to solve this :s

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every element of our matrix is supposed to be non-zero, we have very few cases to consider. For at every position of the matrix, we have $2$ choices for the entry at that position, for a total of $2^4$. We can just go through these $16$ possibilities, and identify the matrices that are non-invertible. The two procedures we describe below are somewhat faster.

We can use the criterion that a matrix is non-invertible if and only if the two rows are linearly dependent. Or else we can use the fact that a matrix over a field is invertible if and only if its determinant is non-zero.

**Solution $1$.** The first row can be any of $1\quad 1$, or $1\quad 2$, or $2\quad 1$, or $2\quad 2$.

For each of these, there are precisely two second rows such that the first row and the second are linearly dependent. For example, if the first row is $1\quad 2$, the two second rows are $1$ times the first row, or $2$ times the first row, that is, $1\quad 2$ and $2\quad 1$.

**Solution $2.$** Let $a$ and $d$ be the entries on the main diagonal. There are $4$ possibilities for the pair $(a,d)$. Our matrix will be non-invertible precisely if its determinant is $0$. This is the case if and only if $cb\equiv ad\pmod{3}$, where $b$ is the second entry in the top row, and $c$ is the first entry in the second row.

Now we can do a case by case analysis. For example, if $a=1$ and $d=2$, we want $cb\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, giving $b=2$ and $c=1$ or the other way around.

**Remark:** For the same problem with $\mathbb{Z}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the same ideas work. For example, let $p=13$. For **any** of the $(12)(12)$ first rows, there are $12$ second rows that give non-invertibility.

Comment: Hey, thanks, interesting solutions. I was introduces to linear dependence and what you say make sense, but we weren't taught this theorem. Just one question: If the rows aren't linearly independent, why does it mean necessarily that there will be a row of zeros after elimination? Thanks!

Regarding the det stuff, we haven't studies that yet.

So I'm pretty puzzeled on how should I solve this.

Comment: If you have not ever done determinant, it is probably best not to worry about the second solution. As to your question, if you have a bunch of rows, and do row eleimination, the new rows give you a set of vectors that span the "row space" of the original matrix. So if we don't get any zero row, then row space is $n$-dimensional, so the original rows are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you! Very nice solutions, and many thanks for the additional explanations!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $A \in M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ is not invertible iff its rows $A_1$ and $A_2$ are colinear. In particular, you can deduce that there are $33$ non invertible matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.